# Problem about bootstrap shadow,nothing happen by using shadow class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootstrap shadow in my code that's why i add the below line of code.But shawod is not working.What is the issue behind this?? Image show the corresponding result..

`<div class="shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">Regular shadow</div>`[image]

Answer (score 1):

please check bootstrap version, shadow utilities is avaible from v4.1.x.